# Excel formula debugging - Median calculation

Tags: debugging, syntax-error, excel-formula, median

I need help in proper formula formatting/syntax.  I just haven’t been able to debug my formula to calculate a Median.  Here is a working formula that calculates an Average:

`=AVERAGEIFS(OFFSET(INDEX(date_city!1:1,MATCH("Price Per SF",date_city!1:1,FALSE)),0,0,COUNTA(INDEX(date_city!1:65521,,MATCH("Price Per SF",date_city!1:1,FALSE))),1), (OFFSET(INDEX(date_city!1:1,MATCH("Date of Sale",date_city!1:1,FALSE)),0,0,COUNTA(INDEX(date_city!1:65521,,MATCH("Date of Sale",date_city!1:1,FALSE))),1)), ">" & Criteria!$F$4, (OFFSET(INDEX(date_city!1:1,MATCH("Date of Sale",date_city!1:1,FALSE)),0,0,COUNTA(INDEX(date_city!1:65521,,MATCH("Date of Sale",date_city!1:1,FALSE))),1)), "<" & Criteria!$G$4)`

I need to modify the above so it calculates a Median.

I’ve tested this simpler formula for proper format and it works:

`{=MEDIAN(IF((date_city!$I$2:$I$989>Criteria!$F$4)*(date_city!$I$2:$I$989<Criteria!$G$4),
date_city!$E$2:$E$221))}`

I need to replace ***date_city!$I$2:$I$989*** and ***date_city!$E$2:$E$221*** from the above Median formula with their corresponding code from the Average formula.

I tried this code, but cannot find my errors.  Probably incorrect parantheses or comma placement.

`=MEDIAN(IF((OFFSET(INDEX(date_city!1:1,MATCH("Date of Sale",date_city!1:1,FALSE)),0,0,COUNTA(INDEX(date_city!1:65521,,MATCH("Date of Sale",date_city!1:1,FALSE))),1)) ">" & Criteria!$F$4)*(OFFSET(INDEX(date_city!1:1,MATCH("Date of Sale",date_city!1:1,FALSE)),0,0,COUNTA(INDEX(date_city!1:65521,,MATCH("Date of Sale",date_city!1:1,FALSE))),1)) "<" & Criteria!$G$4), OFFSET(INDEX(date_city!1:1,MATCH("Price Per SF",date_city!1:1,FALSE)),0,0,COUNTA(INDEX(date_city!1:65521,,MATCH("Price Per SF",date_city!1:1,FALSE))),1)`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[FormulaDesk](http://www.formuladesk.com) can display your formula in a way that is very easy and quick to understand, rolling-up nested parts together with their results. It should also pinpoint exactly where the error is.

*[Disclosure: I am the author of FormulaDesk]*

[image]